# Vulkan visibility operation

Tags: vulkan

Usually we put a memory read access in the dstAccessMask of a memory barrier. However sometimes we also put a memory write access in the dstAccessMask of a memory barrier. e.g.

```
vkCmdCopyImage(image1, image2);

    VkImageMemoryBarrier imageMemoryBarriers{};
    imageMemoryBarriers.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_MEMORY_BARRIER;
    imageMemoryBarriers.srcQueueFamilyIndex = m_queueIndex;
    imageMemoryBarriers.dstQueueFamilyIndex = m_queueIndex;
    imageMemoryBarriers.srcAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_READ_BIT ;
    imageMemoryBarriers.dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_WRITE_BIT ;
    imageMemoryBarriers.oldLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_SRC_OPTIMAL ;
    imageMemoryBarriers.newLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL ;
    imageMemoryBarriers.image = image1;
    kCmdPipelineBarrier(m_commandBuffer, oldStageFlags, newStageFlags, 0, 0, nullptr, 0, nullptr, 1, &imageMemoryBarriers);

vkCmdCopyImage(image3, image1);
```

Because the visibility operation of the memory barrier is usually described by the specs as making writes visible to the dst access which is usually a read, but in this example it is a write, what does the barrier make visible to the dst access then? does it even make sense to make something visible to a memory write access instead of a memory read access at all? Because we don't need anything in the memory to become visible to write to it instead of reading from it?

If possible could you use the specs statements to explain why please? Many thanks!

Comment: "*what does the barrier make visible to the dst access then*" Since `srcAccessMask` is 0, I'd say the answer is nothing. But that'd be true regardless of the destination access mask.

Comment: Thanks @NicolBolas. Sorry I gave a bad example, please see my edited question

Comment: A write-after-read doesn't require visibility at all, since the memory didn't change.

Comment: Sure, so can I interpret it as the barrier call doesn't execute any visibility operation in this case?

Comment: In *which* case? You've changes cases without changing the actual text of your question. At this point, the case described by the text is not represented by the code.

Comment: sorry, I'm a bit confused by your question. I changed the code just to make sure the image has valid content so that you won't give your answer based on the fact that the content of the image is undefined and can focus on what is happening to the dst access. Regarding the text in my question it remains unchanged because it doesn't need to be changed based on what I want to ask. so the latest version of my question (both the text and the code) is the case I mean

Comment: My point is that your text talks about destination write accesses *in general*, while your code only talks about them in the specific case of a prior *read access*. That is, your text implicitly includes the case of a write-after-write, while your code only *shows* write-after-read.

Comment: ah I see. Could you give your answer to both write-after-write and write-after-read cases please?
My guess is that for both cases it executes no visibility operation, as the dst access is a write, so neither cases need the visibility?